# Can not run openapi-generator-cli

Tags: typescript, frontend, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I need generate ts scheme of API via openapi-generator-cli, but error occurs.

I installed openapi-generator-cli globally via npm. Then I added file named swagger.json in root folder of my React project. When run command "openapi-generator-cli generate -i swagger.json -g typescript-axios -o src/api" error occurs:

```
C:\Users\[I am]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\main.js:673
                error ? reject(new Error(stderr)) : resolve(stdout);
                               ^

Error: "java" �� ���� ����७��� ��� ���譥�
��������, �ᯮ��塞�� �ணࠬ��� ��� ������ 䠩���.

    at C:\Users\[I am]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@openapitools\openapi-generator-cli\main.js:673:32
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (node:child_process:430:5)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1105:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:457:11)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (node:net:337:12)
```

Please tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

`openapi-generator-cli` needs Java installed.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old version of Java https://www.java.com/en/download/uninstalltool.jsp